# Asp.NET Core 2 Images

Tags: html, image, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a couple of questions about images, since I don't know what is better for my purposes. Also this might me helpful for other people because I couldn't find this info in other questions.

Well, although this is an asp.net core 2.0 application the first question could is a general question about images.

QUESTION 1

When I have images that I want to load everytime I usually add a query string so the explorers like Chrome or IE don't get the chached image they have. In my case I add the time ticks to the url of the image, this way it loads the image everytime since the query string is always different:

```
filePath += "?" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

But in my case I have a panel where the administrators of the page can change a lot of images. The problem, when they change those images if there is no query string the users are going to see an old image they have stored in their explorer cache.

The question is, if I add the query string to many images is not bad for the performance? is there any other solution for this?

QUESTION 2

I also have photos of the users and other images stored in the site. When I saw a image all the visitors of the site can see the path (for example: www.site.com/user_files/user_001/photo001.jpg). 
Is there a way to hide those paths or transform in another thing is asp.net core 2.0?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Using something like ticks will get the job done, but in a very naive way. You're going to put more stress both on your server and the clients, since effectively the image will have to be refetched every single time, regardless of whether it has changed or not. If you will have any mobile users, the situation is far worse for them, as they'll be forced to redownload all these resources over and over, usually over limited (and costly) data plans.

A far better approach is to use a cryptographic digest, often called a "hash". Essentially, the same data encrypted in the same way will return the same hash. It's usually used to detect tampering with transmitted data, but since each message will (generally) have a unique hash and that hash will be the same each time for the same piece of data, you can also use this to generate a cache-busting query string that only changes when the image data itself changes.

Now, to be thorough, there's technically no guarantee that two messages won't result in the same hash. Instances where that occurs are called "collisions" and they can happen. However, if you use a sufficiently complex algorithm like SHA256, the likelihood of collisions is greatly reduced. Regardless, it should not be a real issue for concern for this particular use case of cache-busting images.

Simplistically, to create the hash, you simply do something like:

```
string hash;
using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
{
    hash = Convert.ToBase64String(sha256.ComputeHash(imageBytes));
}
```

The value of `hash` then will be something like `z1JZs/EwmDGW97RuXtRDjlt277kH+11EEBHtkbVsUhE=`.

However, ASP.NET Core has an `ImageTagHelper` built-in that will handle this for you. Essentially, you just need to do:

```
<img src="/path/to/image.jpg" asp-append-version="true" />
```

As for your second question, about hiding or obfuscating the image path, that's not strictly possible, but can be worked around. The URL you use to reference the image uniquely identifies that resource. If you change it in any way, it's effectively not the same resource any more, and thus, would not locate the actual image you wanted to display. So, in a strict sense, no, you cannot change the URL. However, you can proxy the request through a different URL, effectively obfuscating the URL for the original image.

Simply, you'd just have an action on some controller that takes an image path (as part of the query string), loads that from the filesystem and returns it as a response. Care should be taken limit the scope of files that can be returned like this, both based on directory (only allow your image directory, for example, not `C:\Windows\`, etc.) and file type (only allow images to be returned, not random text files, config files, etc.). That portion is straight-forward enough, and you can find many examples online if you need them.

Ultimately, this doesn't really solve anything, though, because now your image path is simply in the query string instead. However, now that you've set this part up, you can encrypt that part of the query string using the Data Protection API. There's some basic getting started information available in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Essentially, you're just going to encrypt the image path when creating the URL, and then in your action that returns the image, you decrypt the path first before running the rest of the code. For the encryption part, you can [create a tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to do this for you without having to have a ton of logic in your views.

Comment: asp-append-version="true" - who knew! - I'm about finding this as my updated images were never shown unless you force refreshed - and no end user is expected to do that.